# Do I need app Approval from Facebook for posting image?

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an app for an event which is doing take photo and post to own facebook wall by integration. Each time login with a different account and share image or photo to Facebook.
There is much photo Post on the wall with the event detail and its own URL in the caption.

So I want to know that Do I need App Approval from Facebook.

Any appreciation appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need app Approval from Facebook for posting image?

Yep. You need to submit your application to Facebook team for the approval. Here you can see in detail https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review